# nxlog parse_xml() with attributes

Tags: xml, nxlog

I'm learning nxlog but there aren't may examples of parsing xml input in the current docs.

My input lines look like this:

```
<Msg time='2014-06-27T00:27:38' type='ERROR' code='5000' target='Some.Target' machine='DEV-Machine' process='2408' thread='160' elapsed='0.00000'>The message.</Msg>
```

I have

```
<Input my_input>
  Module      im_file
  File        'C:\logs\\*.dat'
  Exec        parse_xml(); to_json();
</Input>
```

Which produces only:

```
{"EventReceivedTime":"2014-06-27 01:13:28","SourceModuleName":"my_input","SourceModuleType":"im_file"}
```

How do I get the attributes into json fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no support for parsing xml attributes or nested xml currently via the xm_xml extension module. 
There is xm_perl which you could use for this kind of complex xml parsing (available for Linux only).

Comment: Darn... It would be nice to use xpath e.g. `parse_xml(); $Message = '/Msg'; $EventTime = '/Msg/@time'` etc...

Comment: btw I was kinda expecting at least the `Msg` xml node text to be available as `$Msg` but that it wasn't, it was null.